# multiple reocrds in one line of asp.net mvc5 gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to do this style in gridview,more than 1000 records in this web page

thanks[image]

Comment: Anyone help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            string @imgpath = "/pictures/" + @item.ArticleNumber + ".jpg";
            <div class="record">
                <img src=@imgpath>
                <br />
                <div>@item.SalesOffice @item.PriceList</div>
            </div>
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                <br />
            }
            i++;
        }
```